# What's wrong with my Nant Record task?

Tags: .net, scripting, ant, build-automation, nant

I have the following in a build script:

```
<record action="Start" autoflush="true" name="${nant.log}"/>
```

The name value is valid. I get the following error message:

*Invalid element <record>.Unknown task or datatype.*

After looking at the documentation I am not sure why this is causing an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do other NAntContrib tasks work properly? What version of NAnt/NAntContrib are you using?

Comment: Jeff - Latest stable. I just downloaded Nant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a configuration problem. There's discussion [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/nant-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05917.html) on how to configure NAntContrib.

From method 2:

> In order to make certain tasks
>   available to every build file, you can
>   copy the tasks assembly and all its
>   dependencies to the "\bin\tasks"
>   directory.

Comment: I have added \taks\net directorys to my nant\bin directory and copied the contribe dlls into it but it doesn't appear to make a difference. I would rather not have to load the assembly in each build file if I can avoid it.

Comment: Hmm. That post may be out of date. (It's from before the release of  0.85). I looked at my system and I have the NAntContrib dlls in C:\nant-05-rc3\bin\ There's also NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.xml in the same directory. Is that what you have?

Comment: So why don't You utilize NAnt's `<loadtask>` task. Find the description on how to do this with the link JeffH provided. Works fine for us.

Comment: @Chairman - While <loadtask> will work, Nick's comment above: "I would rather not have to load the assembly in each build file" suggests that he would have to modify multiple build files, making <loadtask> a second-best solution.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your record task is after the NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll

```
<loadtasks assembly="${path-to-dll}\NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll"/>
<record name="Deploy.log"  
        action="Start" />
```

At least that was what my issue was, I was trying to starting logging before NAnt knew how to log.